# image loaded from database does not show

Tags: php

guys.
I tried to load image stored in mysql blob field with php, but the image does not show correctly. In firebug, I got these infos: get-image.php Dimensions0 × 0File size5.35KBMIME typeimage/jpeg

Here is my code

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo of Database Image in a page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Here is your picture:<br>
    img src=get-image.php?id=1 width=400 height=300><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
include "db.php";
$conn = OpenDbConnection();
$key = $_GET["id"];
$tkey = "" . $key . "";
$strsql = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `image_id` = " . $tkey;
$rs = mysql_query($strsql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
if (!($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))) {
    die("File not exists.");
}
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row["content"];
mysql_free_result($rs);
mysql_close($conn);  
?>
```

Please someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is there an opening `<` on the img tag?  What about quotes on the attributes of the tag (`src="get-image.php?id=1"`, `width="400"`, etc)?

Comment: I assume the `<` for `<img>` is actually there in your code, and just missing from your example code?

Comment: Not to mention the [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability that you have in your image code...  Force `$_GET['id']` to be an integer instead of a string.  So instead of `$tkey = "" . $key . "";`, do something like: `$tkey = (int) $key;`.  PHP will automatically convert from the int to a string when you concatenate it...

Comment: You should download the image and open it in an texteditor or call it directly from the browser. I guess you get there useful information, for example error-messages.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

Instead of

```
echo $row["content"];
```

Use this code

```
   ?>
   <img scr="<?php echo $row["content"];?>" />
   <?php
```

Thanks,

Kanji

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because of blog type. Whenever you upload an image which exceed the limit of blob, then image not displayed correctly. **Try to change type from blob to long blob.**